# Quero saber quantas linhas e colunas uma matriz possui em Python?

Tags: python, matriz

Estou tentando desenvolver um exercício que solicitou a criação de uma função que quando recebe como parâmetro uma matriz, ela retorna a quantidade de linha e de coluna que essa matriz possui.

Eu estou tentando fazer isso com o código abaixo, ainda sem ser uma função, 
mas quando eu tentei com matrizes menores deu errado.

```
n = [[1,2,3,44], [4,5,6,55], [7,8,9,77], [10,20,30,99], [40,50,60,54]]

contlin = 0
contcol = 0

for i in range(len(n)):
    contlin = contlin + 1

for j in range(i):
    contcol = contcol + 1
    print(j, end = ' ')
    print("\n")

print('Total:', contlin, 'X', contcol)
```

Comment: Você tentou: `len(n)` para as linhas e `len(n[0])` para as colunas?

Comment: Lembrando que isso não é uma "matriz" - é uma "lista de listas" - que é uma estrutura de dados bidimensional, e, portanto, pode ser usada como uma matriz. Mas nada impediria, por exemplo, que alguém faça um "append" na lista da 5ª linha, e só aquela linha passe a ter mais elementos. 
Python não tem uma estrutura nativa de dados bidimensional (ou mulitdimensional), mas é bem fácil criar uma classe própria pra isso. Usualmente, no entanto, se usa a biblioteca NumPy que já tem esses objetos muito bem definidos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode calcular as dimensões da sua matriz 2D usando basicamente a técnica:

```
nlinhas = len(m)
ncolunas = len(m[0])
```

Repare que a quantidade de colunas é calculada obtendo-se a quantidade de elementos presente na primeira linha da matriz, isso deixa duas questões em aberto:

**1)** E se a matriz estiver vazia? Nesse caso não há uma primeira linha:

```
m = []
ncolunas = len(m[0]) #IndexError: list index out of range
```

**2)** E se a matriz possuir diversas linhas de tamanhos diferentes:

```
m = [ [1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2] ]
ncolunas = len(m[0]) # 3 ???
```

Para contornar esse tipo de problema, sugiro algo como:

```
def obter_dimensao(m):
    # Verifica se todas as linhas da matriz
    # possuem o mesmo tamnho
    if len({len(i) for i in m}) > 1:
        raise TypeError('Matriz 2D invalida.')

    # Calcula quantidade de linhas na matriz
    linhas = len(m)

    # Se nao houverem linhas na matriz
    # assume zero colunas
    colunas = len(m[0]) if linhas else 0

    return (linhas, colunas)

m1 = []                  # 0x0
m2 = [[],[],[]]          # 3x0
m3 = [[1],[2],[3]]       # 3x1
m4 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]   # 2x3
m5 = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]] # Matriz invalida!

print(obter_dimensao(m1))
print(obter_dimensao(m2))
print(obter_dimensao(m3))
print(obter_dimensao(m4))
print(obter_dimensao(m5))
```

Saída:

```
(0, 0)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(obter_dimensao(m5))
  File "main.py", line 3, in obter_dimensao
    raise TypeError('Matriz 2D invalida.')
TypeError: Matriz 2D invalida.
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SugarySaddlebrownPacket)

Answer (score 0):

O problema do seu código está no segundo laço `for`. O que acontece é que você conta a quantidade de colunas, baseado na quantidade de linhas. O resultado deu certo neste código usando essa matriz por pura coincidência, e eu vou explicar o porquê.

A quantidade de linhas que a matriz possui é `5`, então o retorno do `range` na segunda repetição será números de `0...4`. Agora se a matriz tivesse `4` linhas, o retorno seria números de `0...3`.

Para provar isso, teste retirar uma linha da sua matriz como no exemplo abaixo:

**Matriz:**

```
n = [[1, 2, 3, 44], [4, 5, 6, 55], [7, 8, 9, 77], [10, 20, 30, 99]]
```

**Output:**

```
Total: 4 X 3
```

---

Para contar quantas colunas a sua matriz possui, você deverá "entrar" em cada linha através do **index** delas, que no caso, é a variável `j` da sua segunda repetição.

Uma coisa muito importante que podemos notar, é que todas as linhas possuem o mesmo número de colunas. Logo, não é necessário percorrer as linhas, basta verificar o número de colunas de uma única linha. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
for linha in matriz: # Não é necessário o range() e o len() aqui.
    contlin = contlin + 1

linha = matriz[0]

for coluna in linha:
    contcol = contcol + 1
```

---

Se você não quiser fazer tudo na mão, você pode simplesmente utilizar a função `len()` para contar o número de linhas e colunas, sem precisar de um `for` loop.

Veja abaixo a função que eu criei para obter o tamanho da matriz:

```
def obter_tamanho(matriz):

  linhas = len(matriz)
  colunas = len(matriz[0])

  return linhas, colunas


matriz = [[1, 2, 3, 44], [4, 5, 6, 55], [7, 8, 9, 77]]
tamanho = obter_tamanho(matriz)

print('Total: {} X {}'.format(*tamanho))
```

Answer (score 0):

Matriz é um caso especial de lista bidimensional em que cada linha de dados possui o mesmo número de elementos ou seja uma lista de listas com igual comprimento.

Ciente disso e como foi comentado para obter o número de linhas e o número de colunas de uma matriz você pode utilizar a função nativa do python [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) que retorna o número de elementos de um objeto:

```
matriz = [[ 1, 2, 3,44], 
          [ 4, 5, 6,55], 
          [ 7, 8, 9,77], 
          [10,20,30,99], 
          [40,50,60,54]]

print (f'Número de linhas: {len(matriz)}')
print (f'Número de colunas: {len(matriz[0])}') #basta medir a primeira linha pois as outras terão o mesmo comprimento.
```

<sub>Código no Repli.it: https://repl.it/repls/NextWhichBrain</sub>

Ou então utilizar a biblioteca [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) que é o pacote fundamental para a computação científica com Python que também fornece funções para trabalhar com matrizes e algebra linear.

Para criar uma matriz com NumPy use a função [`array()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) e para medir o comprimento da array em um dos seus eixos use a função [`size()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.size.html) com parâmetro `axis` setado em `0` para linhas e `1` para colunas.

```
import numpy as np

matriz = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3,44],
                   [ 4, 5, 6,55], 
                   [ 7, 8, 9,77], 
                   [10,20,30,99], 
                   [40,50,60,54]])

print (f'Número de linhas: {np.size(matriz, 0)}')
print (f'Número de colunas: {np.size(matriz, 1)}')
```

<sub>Código no Repli.it: https://repl.it/repls/BluevioletLonelyBrackets</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a biblioteca do [Numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/) para isso. Existe uma função lá dentro chamda [shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) e ela geralmente é usada para se obter a "**forma**" atual de uma matriz qualquer. Por exemplo:

```py
from numpy import array

numpy_array = array([[1, 2, 3], [10, 15, 20]])

print(numpy_array.shape)
```

Isso vai imprimir algo assim:

```
(2,3)
```

Onde 2 é referente as linhas e 3 as colunas

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade há outra maneira:

```
Matriz1 = [[1,2,3,4],[2,4,6,16],[4,8,12,45],[10,20,30,67],[1,2,3,67]]

Matriz2 = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]

Matriz3 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

Vamos supor as 3 matrizes, acima, não-quadradas de ordem, respectivamente iguais a: (5 X 4), (10 X 2) e (3 X 6).

Uma maneira simples de se determinar a quantidade de colunas consiste em:

1) Encontrar a quantidade de linhas: `nlinhas = len(Matriz)`

2) Encontrar a quantidade de elementos: `nElementos = len(Matriz[0])`

3) Por fim, o `ncolunas = nElementos/nlinhas`

O algoritmo fica assim:

```
nlinhas = 0
nElementos = 0
#ncolunas = 0

for i in range(len(Matriz)):

    nlinhas += 1

    for j in range(len(Matriz[0])):

        nElementos += 1

ncolunas = (nElementos/nlinhas)

print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('\nNúmero de linhas: ' +str(nlinhas)+'\n'  + '\nNúmero de colunas: '+str(ncolunas)+'\n')
print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Se usarmos Matriz1, Matriz2 e Matriz3, nessa ordem, encontraremos:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Número de linhas: 5

Número de colunas: 4.0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Número de linhas: 10

Número de colunas: 2.0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Número de linhas: 3

Número de colunas: 6.0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```